# Get Hidden Parameter Value Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html.

```
<td style="text-align:left;" class="product-quantity">
    <input type="hidden" value="ABC" class="skuhidden">
    <div class="quantity buttons_added"><input type="button" class="minus" value="-"></div>                     
</td>
```

Now i want to access value of hidden parameter with class name `skuhidden` on click of button with classname minus. There are multiple parameter with same class name so i want the closest hidden value to the button within the class minus.

I tried this

`$(.minus).siblings('.skuhidden').val()`

but it is not working. Please Help me.

Comment: you forgot `""` in `$(".minus")` the quotes are important you know if you forget it then jquery searches for the variable `.minus`

Answer (score 4):

As `skuhidden` element is not a sibling of `minus` element thus your code doesn't work.

You can use [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find td then you can use [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to locate `skuhidden` element

```
$('.minus').closest('td.product-quantity').find('.skuhidden').val();
```

*OR*

Find parent div and then use `siblings()`.

```
$('.minus').closest('.quantity').siblings('.skuhidden').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get all form fields that are hidden
var hidden_fields = $( this ).find( 'input:hidden' );

// Filter those which have a specific type
hidden_fields.attr( 'text' );
```

try this .i hope  it help you